# Spring: Pass object to RestController from Application

Tags: java, spring

So I am busy writing a Spring Boot app but I cannot seem to find out out how I can pass an object to my RestController from my main application.

Here is my Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("webservices")
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Application app = new Application(ctx);
        LinkedBlockingQueue<RawDate> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        // do other stuff here
    }
}
```

And here is my RestController:

```
@RestController
public class GoogleTokenController {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<RawData> queue;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/google/token", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
    @ResponseBody    
    public String googleToken(@RequestBody AuthCode authCode) {
        System.out.println("CODE: " + authCode.getAuthCode());
        // do other stuff here
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

So I want to pass the same instance of `LinkedBlockingQueue<RawData>` that is created in the `Application` class to the `GoogleTokenController` class. But I have no idea how to do that since spring automatically creates the `GoogleTokenController` class.

Please note I am very new to Spring. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the object that you want to pass a Spring bean and let Spring inject it into the controller. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("webservices")
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public LinkedBlockingQueue<RawDate> queue() {
        return new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Application app = new Application(ctx);
        // do other stuff here
    }
}

@RestController
public class GoogleTokenController {
    @Autowired // Let Spring inject the queue
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<RawData> queue;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/google/token", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
    @ResponseBody    
    public String googleToken(@RequestBody AuthCode authCode) {
        System.out.println("CODE: " + authCode.getAuthCode());
        // do other stuff here
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

In other places where you need access to `queue`, also let Spring inject it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but the queue variable in GoogleTokenController is null if I do this.

Comment: @ArmandMaree Are you creating the `GoogleTokenController` yourself with `new GoogleTokenController()`? Don't do that (that's the #1 mistake people make with Spring dependency injection) - let Spring create the `GoogleTokenController`.

Comment: No I am not creating the GoogleTokenController. Spring does it by itself.

Comment: Nevermind, your solution is working now, I made a stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a component that you can inject into your controller? You could create a seperate class for the Queue as

```
@Component
public class RawDateQueue extends LinkedBlockingQueue<RawDate> {
    // no further implementations
}
```

and use RawDateQueue in your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

use -:

```
  @autowired 
   private LinkedBlockingQueue<RawData> queue;

    OR

   @inject 
   private LinkedBlockingQueue<RawData> queue;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.